# Can't log in or add new admins after delete was created

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, authentication, admin

I'm in a course in udemy about web development and I've found that the code showing have some errors (i'm not the only one), so after more than a month without answer from the tutor I would live if you could help me.

This code is about making a log in to the "admin" área, creating new admins, editing and deleting them. The code was working fine until the "eliminar" (delete) was added, it pop up the alert when I click delete, but dont delete the items in the MySQL and that's not the only problem. When i tried to log in, it seems like it didnt let me until I deleted the delete code, same problem when i tried to add new admins, so I tried to ask for help in the course with no success and searched for new solutions in the other students problems, but most of them where as lost as I am. Could you please help me fix it?

pd. I'm beyond refound, I'm in the video 457/500 and more time than a month have passed, so I cant ask for it even if I want it.

Here is the model:

```
<?php
include_once 'funciones/funciones.php';
  $usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
  $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
  $password=$_POST['password'];
  $id_registro =$_POST['id_registro'];

if($_POST['registro'] == 'nuevo') {
    $opciones=array(
      'cost'=>12
    );
    $password_hashed=password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $opciones);
    try {
      $stmt=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO admins(usuario, nombre, password) VALUES (?,?,?)");
      $stmt->bind_param("sss", $usuario, $nombre, $password_hashed);
      $stmt->execute();
      $id_registro=$stmt->insert_id;
      if ($id_registro > 0) {
        $respuesta=array(
          'respuesta'=>'exito',
          'id_admin'=>$id_registro
        );
      } else {
        $respuesta=array(
          'respuesta'=>'error',
        );
      }
      $stmt->close();
      $conn->close();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    die(json_encode($respuesta));
}

if($_POST['registro'] == 'actualizar') {

  try {
    if (empty($_POST['password']) )  {
      $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE admins SET usuario = ?, nombre = ?, editado = NOW() WHERE id_admin = ? ");
      $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $usuario, $nombre, $id_registro);
    } else {
      $opciones = array(
        'cost' => 12
      );
      $hash_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $opciones );
      $stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE admins SET usuario = ?, nombre = ?, password = ?, editado = NOW() WHERE id_admin = ? ');
      $stmt->bind_param("sssi", $usuario, $nombre, $hash_password, $id_registro);
    }

    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->affected_rows) {
      $respuesta = array(
        'respuesta' => 'exito',
        'id_actualizado' => $stmt->insert_id
      );
    }else {
      $respuesta = array(
        'respuesta' => 'error'
      );
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
  } catch (\Exception $e) {
      $respuesta = array(
        'respuesta' => $e->getMessage()
      );
  }
  die(json_encode($respuesta));
}

if($_POST['registro'] == 'eliminar') {
  //die(json_encode($_POST));
  $id_borrar = $_POST['id'];

    try {
      $stmt = $conn->prepare('DELETE FROM admins WHERE id_admin = ? ');
      $stmt->bind_param('i', $id_borrar);
      $stmt->execute();
      if($stmt->affected_rows){
        $respuesta = array(
          'respuesta' => 'correcto',
          'id_eliminado' => $id_borrar
        );
      } else {
          $respuesta = array(
            'respuesta' => 'cancel'
          );
      }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $respuesta = array{
          'respuesta' => $e->getMessage();
        };
    }
    die(json_encode($respuesta));
}


if(isset($_POST['login-admin'])) {
  $usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
  $password=$_POST['password'];

  //die(json_encode($_POST));
  try {
    include_once 'funciones/funciones.php';
    $stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM admins WHERE usuario = ?;");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $usuario);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id_admin, $usuario_admin, $nombre_admin, $password_admin, $editado);
    if ($stmt->affected_rows) {
      $existe=$stmt->fetch();
      if ($existe) {
        if(password_verify($password, $password_admin)){
          session_start();
          $_SESSION['usuario']=$usuario_admin;
          $_SESSION['nombre']=$nombre_admin;
          $respuesta=array(
            'respuesta'=>'exitoso',
            'usuario'=>$nombre_admin
          );
        } else {
          $respuesta=array(
            'respuesta'=>'error'
          );
        }
      } else {
        $respuesta=array(
          'respuesta'=>'error'
        );
      }
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
  } catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
  die(json_encode($respuesta));
}
?>
```

Here is the admin-ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#guardar-registro').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

          var datos = $(this).serializeArray();

          $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            data: datos,
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
             console.log(data);
             var resultado = data;
             if(resultado.respuesta == 'exito'){
              Swal.fire(
                'Correcto!',
                'El administrador se creo correctamente!',
                'success'
              )
            }else {
              Swal.fire(
                'Error!',
                'Hubo un error!',
                'Error'
              )
            }

            }

          })
    });

    // eliminar registros
    $('.borrar-registro').on('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let id = $(this).attr('data-id');
      let tipo = $(this).attr('data-tipo');
      Swal.fire({
        title: '¿Estás seguro?',
        text: "Un registro eliminado no se puede recuperar",
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Si, Eliminar!',
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar'
      }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            data: {
              'id': id,
              'registro': 'eliminar'
            },
            url: 'modelo-' + tipo + '.php',
            success: function (data) {
              var resultado = JSON.parse(data);
              if (resultado.respuesta == 'correcto') {
                Swal.fire(
                  'Eliminado!',
                  'Se eliminó el registro de la dase de datos.',
                  'success'
                )
                jQuery('[data-id="' + resultado.id_eliminado + '"]').parents('tr').remove();
              }
            }
          })
        } else if (result.dismiss === 'cancel') {
          Swal.fire(
            'Cancelado',
            'No se eliminó el registro',
            'error'
          )
        }
      })
    });

    $('#login-admin').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
          var datos = $(this).serializeArray();
          $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            data: datos,
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                var resultado = data;
                if(resultado.respuesta == 'exitoso'){
                 Swal.fire(
                   'Login Correcto!',
                   'Bienvenido '+resultado.usuario+' !!',
                   'success'
                 )
                 setTimeout(function(){
                   window.location.href = 'admin-area.php';
                 }, 2000);
               }else {
                 Swal.fire(
                   'Error!',
                   'Usuario o Password Incorrecto! !',
                   'Error'
                 )
               }
            }

          })
    });

});
```

pdd. Im sorry, I know I'm bad at this, but thank you for your time.

Edit 1: I can log in and add new admins again if I delete the "eliminar" (delete) part added again, that was an error in my pc I gess, but still can't do it with the delete part.

Comment: Try changing this `die(json_encode($respuesta));` to `echo json_encode($respuesta);` and see if the json data is sending back to ajax or not .

Comment: I tried to change it with echo, but nothing happen

Comment: Does you browser console showing any error ? Also does `id` value is correct or not ? Do `alert(data)` or `console.log(data)` to see what is coming back from server to php.

Comment: Yes, it shows this error when i try to add/delete an admin: jquery.min.js:2 POST http://localhost:85/webcamp/admin/modelo-admin.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

(sorry, but where should i put the console.log(data)? i'm putting it in the wrong place i asume, since i only get the same error)

Comment: After this line `success: function (data) {  console.log(data)..` . You have server error make sure that `$_POST` is not null .

Comment: It's not showing anything, and that's weird because it was usefull before everything that's there. I think the "then((result) is giving a problem i dont understand, like missing the data or id from the query. I'm really lost with this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219501/discussion-between-henry-aranda-and-swati).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working now, this is how it end up and thanks to @Swati for the help and time given.

modelo admin:

```
if ($_POST['registro'] == 'eliminar') {
$id_borrar = $_POST['id'];
try {
$stmt = $conn->prepare('DELETE FROM admins WHERE id_admin = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id_borrar);
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->affected_rows){
$respuesta = array(
'respuesta' => 'exito',
'id_eliminado' => $id_borrar
);
}else {
$respuesta = array(
'respuesta' => 'error'
);
}
} catch (Exception $e) {
$respuesta = array(
'respuesta' => $e->getMessage()
);
}
die(json_encode($respuesta));
}
```

admin ajax:

```
$('.borrar_registro').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
let id = $(this).attr('data-id');
let tipo = $(this).attr('data-tipo');
Swal.fire({
title: '¿Estás Seguro?',
text: "Un usuario eliminado no se puede recuperar",
type: 'warning',
showCancelButton: true,
confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
confirmButtonText: 'Si, Eliminar',
cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar'
}).then((result) => {
if (result.value) {
$.ajax({
type: 'post',
data: {
'id': id,
'registro': 'eliminar'
},
url: 'modelo-' + tipo + '.php',
success: function(data) {
console.log(data);
let resultado = JSON.parse(data);
if (resultado.respuesta === 'exito') {
Swal.fire(
'¡Eliminado!',
'El registro a sido eliminado',
'success'
)
jQuery('[data-id="' + resultado.id_eliminado + '"]').parents('tr').remove();
} else {
Swal.fire(
'¡Error!',
'No se pudo eliminar',
'error'
)}
}
})
} else if (result.dismiss === 'cancel') {
console.log(id);
Swal.fire(
'Cancelado',
'No se eliminó el registro',
'error'
)
}
});
});
```